# Lumen Encrypted Key Decrypt in Node JS

Tags: encryption, lumen, cryptojs

I have a session cookie which is encrypted in Lumen Framework.

https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption

I am trying to decrypt cookie in Node Js using crypto-js but I get an error message Error: **Malformed UTF-8 data at Object.stringify**

I have been stuck on this for a day not sure what I am doing wrong !!

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: source code decrypting the cookie could be helpful, did you find how the laravel is encrypting the session cookie?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was able to fix it by looking at the source code and the code shared below. I had to make minor adjustments in the code below but it works

https://gist.github.com/Agoreddah/511864e2c00da064586523b3087c30e2#file-encrypter-js